# How to upgrade apache, php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache-2.2, debian-lenny

I'm looking to update our web server, and my experience with updating is slim. I have done clean installs of apache, php, and mysql, but this will be my first time upgrading. Hoping someone can give me detailed instructions on how to do this.

I'm on PHP 5.2.6 and mysql 5.051, and I'm looking to get those to the current versions. I have apache installed on Debian (Lenny).

(Has anyone had any major issues performing these upgrades?)

NOTE: Looking to upgrade versions to PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 1):

Some few steps

1. Please check the [manual](http://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#minimal-upgrade).
2. Be aware of [PHP 5.3 and 5.2 differences](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php)
3. The same to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

The Debian Squeeze release notes has a [whole chapter](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.html) about upgrading from Lenny.

If you just want to keep the packages updated, without changing the version of your whole distribution, you just need to check for updates once on a while:

```
 # aptitude update
 # aptitude safe-upgrade
```

You may prefer to use `apt-get`

```
 # apt-get update
 # apt-get dist-upgrade
```